# String validation using regular expressions in bash

Tags: regex, string, bash, awk

I've been having a hard time getting regular expressions locked down in bash. I'm writing a script that's meant to read a file which contains a list of names. And I'm meant to validate each name.

File is like so:

```
John, Smith
Jane, Doe S.
stan, smith
```

The format of a valid name is as follows:

- Must have a last and first name separated by a comma.
- First name must start with a capital letter followed by small letters (the same goes for the last name).
- The middle name initial is optional, but if it does exist, it must be a capital letter and must be followed by a period(`.`).

This means only the first two names in the file are valid.
I've been tugging a this for a while now. Could anyone please help?

I have tried expressions such as

```
if [[ "${name}" =~ "^[A-Z]{1}[a-z]" ]]
```

to at least validate the last name. But it obviously doesn't work.

Comment: Exactly! @Aaron but it says all of them are invalid

Comment: Hmm actually `^`  doesn't seem to be understood as a metacharacter *when the pattern is quoted*  : `[[ "foo" =~ "^foo" ]] && echo ok` fails, while `[[ "foo" =~ ^foo ]] && echo ok` succeeds

Comment: @Aaron You're correct, if the pattern is quoted, it's interpreted as a string, not a pattern.

Comment: @Aaron removing the quotes did help a bit. Now I see a path to follow. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is good practice to declare the pattern in a separate variable and then just use that variable, as this avoids quoting problems and is compatible with all Bash versions that support regular expressions<sup>1</sup>:

```
re='^[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+, [[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+( [[:upper:]]\.)?$'
while read -r name; do
    [[ $name =~ $re ]] && echo "$name matches"
done < infile
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Regular expression parsing changed between Bash versions 3.1 and 3.2, see [Chet's FAQ](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/FAQ), E14.

Comment: Works like a charm. Really need to do some studying of regular expressions. Could you explain what the last part of the expression means?        "+( [[:upper:]].)?"

Comment: @DuckDodgers The `+` is part of the `[[:lower:]]` preceding it, meaning "one or more of these". Then, `( [[:upper:]\.)?` (I inserted the backslash just now!) is "a space, an uppercase character, a period" (escaped as `\.` because `.` is "any character"), and the `?` at the end means "zero or one of these", i.e., optional.

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Better to use `awk` for this instead of `BASH`:

```
awk -F '[[:blank:]]*,[[:blank:]]*' '
$1 ~ /^[A-Z][a-z]*$/ && $2 ~ /^[A-Z][a-z]*( [A-Z]\.)?$/' file
```

```
John, Smith
Jane, Doe S.
```

**Details:**

- `-F '[[:blank:]]*,[[:blank:]]*'` splits each line into fields with delimiter as comma surrounded by optional spaces on both sides.
- `$1 ~ /^[A-Z][a-z]*$/`: Checks if first name starts with upper case letter followed by lower case letters.
- `$2 ~ /^[A-Z][a-z]*( [A-Z]\.)?$/`: Checks if first name starts with upper case letter followed by lower case letters. There is an **optional** match for middle name as well which is just an upper case letter followed by dot.

Comment: This works fine. I'll read up some more on awk. Thanks